# Extracting Last Character of a TypeScript String Literal

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to extract the last character of a string? I'm doing with numeric digits right now so I don't need to write the whole alphabet as an enum.

I'm also somewhat confused about why what I wrote isn't working properly.

```
type Digit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | '0';

type GetFirstDigitOfStringLiteralNumber<T extends `${string}${Digit}`> = T extends `${infer D extends Digit}${string}` ? D : never;
type GetLastDigitOfStringLiteralNumber<T extends `${string}${Digit}`> = T extends `${string}${infer D extends Digit}` ? D : never;

// This is correct
type FirstCharacter = GetFirstDigitOfStringLiteralNumber<"21222">;
//    ^? "2"
// This is correct
type LastCharacter1 = GetLastDigitOfStringLiteralNumber<"12">;
//    ^? "2"
// This is incorrect
type LastCharacter2 = GetLastDigitOfStringLiteralNumber<"21222">;
//    ^? '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | '0'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgSwOYJDAvDA5ABizAH2wEZ8isAmM7AZmqwBZ6BWegNnoHZ6AOegTnp4A3MFCRYAcSggAYggBOAZxCIUIAPIAzAMogFCAHZIAMqigKAhgBsAcgFcAtgCMLAHgAqMKAA8QUQwATJRgAAwASAG8VA2MAXyi1VDjQgD4MGC9ffyCQiMijLQt4bz8A4PhkZKiYoyQUmAB+EoAuGEMoADcLUXBoGGkQE0sVJM1dfTqzfys7J1cFT1Kcivza+MSqkBT0zCyy3LCayY2CwyKFEuzykLGG5rgYNo7uhVFxfo8oFWIMwfllKotto9LFTOZZg4XO4AEQUYgUREw1KiAD0qJgmJgAD1Gh9YF8VBQ-jJhqNgRMwdMLDYoQs3HCEUiUcB0VicY0gA)

The `LastChracter2` not working is really surprising to me. What I'm guessing to be going on is TypeScript doesn't correctly figure out what the `${string}` portion is, and gives up on the static analysis because of that.

But that doesn't explain to me why it doesn't simply return `never` in the case that it can't match the `Digit` portion to a specific character.

Edit:

Giving the `${string}` portion an inferred name seems to cause the `never` result I expected, despite not changing anything else:

```
type Digit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | '0';

type GetLastDigitOfStringLiteralNumber<T extends `${string}${Digit}`> = T extends `${infer L extends string}${infer D extends Digit}` ? D : never;

// This is working
type InferLeading = GetLastDigitOfStringLiteralNumber<"12">;
//    ^? "2"

// Why is this breaking?
type InferLeading2 = GetLastDigitOfStringLiteralNumber<"112">;
//      ^? never
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work because because using `${infer L}${infer R}` on a string longer than two characters will always infer the first char as `L` and the rest as `R`. So for `"123456"`, `L` would be `"1"` and `R` would be `"23456"`. Checking if `R extends Digit` leads to the wrong behavior if `R` is not a single char.

To fix this you can make the type recursive.

```
type GetLastDigitOfStringLiteralNumber<T extends `${string}${Digit}`> = 
  T extends `${string}${infer REST extends `${infer L}${Digit}`}` 
    ? GetLastDigitOfStringLiteralNumber<REST> 
    : T
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=8&pln=5&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAIgSwOYJDAvDA5ABizAH2wEZ8isAmM7AZmqwBZ6BWegNnoHZ6AOegTnp4A3MFCRYAcSggAYggBOAZxCIUIAPIAzAMogFCAHZIAMqigKAhgBsAcgFcAtgCMLAHgAqMKAA8QUQwATJRgAAwASAG8VA2MAXyi1VDjQgD4MGC9ffyCQiMijLQt4bz8A4PhkZKiYoyQUmAB%20EoAuGEMoADcLUXBoGGkQE0sVJM1dfTqzfys7J1cFT1Kcivza%20MSqkBT0zGAYTOXyvJrJjYLDIoUYACUAUR0sstywqMLikwTIsZSG-YOmgMZMNRlttHpYqZzLMHC53PdHul-gc2h5-mI%20rAPFAVMQMoN5MpVGCJpDphYbLCFm4AEQUYgURk01KiAD0rIBMAAeo1xP1sSoKPjgSNiepwWcoTNKfN3HSGRQ2My2RyATygA)